# how to secure faye message to be received by client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, faye

I am using Faye to send messages to subscriber. I need to secure the message be received by the subscriber but I know there is a possiblity that faye messages being lost in the network. For example if the subscriber is not online, the message cannot be received...

My question is: is there a way that the Faye server knows that the message has been received by the subscriber if it knows some kind of the identity of the subscriber. Or is there a protocol that can be used in place of Faye and also ensure the message's security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faye doesn't support durable messages, so you need to roll your own.  One way is to wrap your messages with JSON and use a time stamp for each message.  Then, when the subscriber connects, it would send a message to the publisher/producer requesting all messages after it's last valid timestamp.  The server would have to save critical messages and re-send on request.  And, the other consumers would have to ignore messages that were earlier than there last valid time stamp.

The JSON wrapper would look something like this:

```
{
    ts: 1408628582074,
    version: "1.0",
    message:{
        "alert":"producer is now active..."
    }
}
```

Where the "message" node could be any object, including a string.

There is an open source node project based on Faye that will help you with this [here](https://github.com/darrylwest/node-messaging-commons).